# Is there a way to access the menubar icons using the keyboard?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, keyboard, menu-bar

I know how to use the menu items using only the keyboard. Is there anyway I can access the icons in the top right as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have "Use all <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc. keys as standard function keys" **checked** in System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> moves the keyboard focus to the icons in the menubar

If you have "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" **unchecked** in System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> moves the keyboard focus to the icons in the menubar

Although the leftmost user-installed ones on my computer cannot be accessed, you can then use the cursor keys to move <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> to bring up the menu associated with the icon.

In addition, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> +<kbd>F2</kbd>) moves keyboard focus to the menubar items.

Comment: Ctrl + Fn + F8 works too!

Comment: @c0smikdebris Ah, yes. Thanks! This means you don't need to check the "Use all F1, F2..." setting if you use the Fn key. Would you mind if I added this to the answer?

Comment: Ctrl + Fn + F8 only works for SOME of these icons.  The ones I rarely use, not the ones added by applications.  Like the one for my VPN.