# How to access user installed menubar icons with the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, menu-bar

I understand that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> can be used to access the built-in Apple menu and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> can be used to access program menus (e.g. this [existing answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50825/11747)).

However, I have a bunch of user-installed items in the menu bar (e.g. Better Touch Tool, Caffeine, Alfred, Dropbox, etc.) and neither of the above key combinations allow access to these items.

How can I access the user-installed items in the menu bar using the keyboard?

Comment: Unless they've been implemented in the right way, I don't think it's possible. I can access iStat Menus' stuff with the keyboard and that's definitely 3rd party. The others are inaccessible.

Comment: @ratbum you should post your comment as the answer.  It cannot be done is a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

Install [Bartender](https://macbartender.com). I'm a huge fan for *many* reasons; but amongst those, it allows Spotlight-like quick-filtering of menubar items:

### `⇧⌘␣` …

[image]

### … `drop` …

[image]

### `↩`!

[image]

Look, ma! No mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Unless they've been implemented in the right way, I don't think it's possible. I can access iStat Menus' stuff with the keyboard and that's definitely 3rd party. The others are inaccessible.

Posting my comment as a real answer following Deesbek's suggestion.